Importing XML from SharePoint by looping through a set of variables
I am trying to loop through a set of variables to edit the URL which is being used to grab XML from a SharePoint (specifically the contents of user groups.   The URL for each group varies only by a 3 or 4 digit number.
I can make the code work by manually editing the URL in the XmlImport URL statement but when I try to make it variable it fails (this is before I have tried to loop through an array of the data).
In the code below I have make the commented out section work by manually changing the variable (in this case (6587).  When I debug.print to show the URL I have built it appears to be the same as the working commented out one but it doesn't work
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim new_name As String
Dim Sheet_number As Long
Dim URL_String As String

'loop through the array when I have one!

WS_name = ActiveSheet.Name
new_name = "Prog Leadership - Secure"
Sheet_number = 6587

URL_String = """URL.com/sites/FSCC/_api/Web/SiteGroups/getbyid(" & Sheet_number & ")/Users"""
Debug.Print URL_String


ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:=URL_String _
    , ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")

'    ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= _
        "https://URL.com/sites/FSCC/_api/Web/SiteGroups/getbyid(6587)/Users" _
        , ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")

I have looked at Insert Source Url when Importing XML using VBA in Excel and hoped I'd found an answer but it doesn't appear to work for me so I am obviously doing something silly - hopefully you can help me correct my code.

Too many quotes:  URL_String = "URL.com/sites/FSCC/_api/Web/SiteGroups/getbyid(" & Sheet_number & ")/Users"

@TimWilliams Thank you!  I had thought that the XML expression needed those quotes.  It works just fine with your change :)  Now to get on with looping through all the lists.

URL_String = """URL.com/sites/FSCC/_api/Web/SiteGroups/getbyid(" & Sheet_number & ")/Users"""

should be:
URL_String = "URL.com/sites/FSCC/_api/Web/SiteGroups/getbyid(" & Sheet_number & ")/Users"

You don't need those extra quotes
